# syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in subquwery

Tags: php, sql

[i have syntax error in line 213 please need some help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OkbU.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Look at the line before it. Is that how you end an echo statement? It's not how anyone else ends an echo statement.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Link only questions (and answers) are likely to be down voted. Please post code directly (with proper formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The referenced code contains a number of issues (an undefined variable `$no` on line 218, and what looks like a mysql query being run within an `echo` to name a few...), however, without elaborating on the particulars of each issue, I would suggest the following to simplify your code and make it easier to debug: First build your output within a variable and then echo it to the browser ***after*** executing both queries, like so (edit begins on line 203 of your code):

```
    $output = '';

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($guest))
    {
       $output.= '<tr>';
       $output.= '<td align=\"center\">'.$row["ID_guest"].'</td>';
       $output.= '<td align=\"center\">'.$row["First_name"].' '.$row["Last_name"].'</td>';
       $output.= '<td align=\"center\">'.$row["Check_In_Date"].'</td>';
       $output.= '<td>'.$row["Check_Out_Date"].'</td>';
       $output.= '<td>'.$row["Request_Date"].'</td>';
       $output.= '<td align=\"center\">'.$row["No_Of_Room"].'</td>';
       $output.= '<td align=\"center\">'.$row["Category_Name"].'</td>';
       $output.= '<td align=\"center\"><select>';

       $roomsql = "SELECT...";
       $roomresult = mysql_query($roomsql);
       while($rooms=mysql_fetch_array($roomresult))
       {
          $output.= '<option>'.$rooms['Room_No'].'</option>';
       }

       $output.= '</select></td>';
       $output.= '</tr>';
    }

    echo($output);
```